# How to use "pointer to array 10 of int"?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int(* a)[10];  //declare a as pointer to array 10 of int
    int b[10];    // taken a array of 10 int
    b[2]=32;       
    a=&b;      
    printf("b is on %p\n",&b);
    printf("a is on %p\n",a);
    printf("magic is %d\n",a[2]); // why this is not showing 32
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
b is on 0xbfa966d4
a is on 0xbfa966d4
magic is -1079417052
```

Here I have taken `a` as **pointer to array 10 of int** which points to the array `b`, so now why am I unable to get the value of 32 on `a[2]`?

`a[2]`  is evaluated as `*(a+2)` so now a has address of array `b` so `*(b+2)` and `*(a+2)` are similar so why am I not getting value 32 here?

---

**Edit :**
i got answer by using

```
(*a)[2]
```

but i am not getting how it works ...
see 
when

`a[2]` is `*(a+2)` and `a+2` is a plus `2 * sizeof(int[10])` bytes.

this way     `(*a)[2]` how expand?

Comment: (*a)[2] would be the same as a[0][2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the rules of pointer arithmetic, `a[2]` is `*(a+2)` and `a+2` is `a` plus `2 * sizeof(int[10])` bytes.

(Think of an ordinary `int *p`; `p+1` is `p` plus `sizeof(int)` bytes and `(char *)(p + 1)` is different from `(char *)p + 1`. Now replace `int` with `int[10]`)

Comment: @Eregrith: I think that would violate the strict aliasing rule and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: when a[2] is *(a+2) and a+2 is a plus 2 * sizeof(int[10])  this way how (*a)[2] will expand?

Comment: `*a` is an `int[10]`, more specifically `b`, so this fetches the third element in `b`.

Comment: It will become `*((*a) + 2)` that's to say `*(b + 2)` so `b[2]`

Comment: @Eregrith: no, it will work just fine. Your reasoning assumes `a` is an `int*` and your final remark makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

Since `a` is already a pointer, you have to dereference it in order to refer to the array that it points to:

```
(*a)[2]
```

Comment: This is called "single line substitution" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int(* a)[10];  //declare a as pointer to array 10 of int
    int b[10];    // taken a arry of 10 int
    b[2]=32;       
    a=&b;      
    printf("b is on %p\n",&b);
    printf("a is on %p\n",a);
    printf("magic is %p\n",a + 2); // Changed to show pointer arithmetic
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the following:

```
b is on 0xbfe67114
a is on 0xbfe67114
magic is 0xbfe67164
```

Do you see what's going on? `magic` minus `a` equates `80`, that is, 4 * 10 * 2.
This is because `a` is a pointer to an array of ten integers, so `sizeof(*a) == 10 * sizeof(int)` and not `sizeof(a) == sizeof(int)`, which is what you was expecting to.
Pay attention to types in pointer arithmetic next time!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to add a comment here since it requires 50 reputation. So here goes my question for the question posted. 
Sorry if I will be violating some of  the rules by posting the question in the answer box. 
This question shows that we should be careful while performing pointer arithmetic. But what is the good use of using pointers to an array if same thing could be done just by using pointers to integers ....?

Answer (score -1):

int b[10] == `int*` that points to the first value in the array

int (*a)[10] == `int**` that point to the address of a pointer that points to an array

`a+2 == (&b)+2`

Hope this clears things up for you

Comment: This is wrong. `b` is not `int*`, `a` is not `int**`, and `int* a[10]` is different from `int (*a)[10]`.

Comment: @interjay Yeah, the way I wrote it first would produce me an array of 10 int*. But `b` is an `int*`

Comment: No, `b` is not an `int*`, but it can decay to an `int*` in some (not all) contexts. However, `a` will never decay to an `int**` because they behave completely differently. And your line about `a` pointing to the address of a pointer is wrong as well.

Comment: @interjay well when taken out of the context of the question it is wrong, but in his case it is true. Will try to answer the question more generally next time